# Tratar datos en MySQL con archivo php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo el modelo de datos del servidor de una app, para esto estoy haciendo el login, modificar, borrar, añadir, consultar usuarios y me está dando un error a la hora de ejecutar el .php que ataca a la BBDD. He buscado el error pero no me funciona o no entiendo las soluciones que proponen... Pongo el código del php y el resultado que obtengo.

En este caso (BORRAR) estoy probando de poner el nombre de usuario directamente (B) para ver si era a la hora de recoger parámetros... Pero no.

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
//$usu_usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$usu_usuario="B";

$sql = "delete from user where username=?";

$sentencia=$conexion->prepare($sql);
$sentencia->bind_param('s', $usu_usuario);
$sentencia->execute();

$resultado = $sentencia->get_result();

if ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo json_encode($fila,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);     
}
$sentencia->close();
$conexion->close();
?>
```

AÑADIR

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
//$usu_usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
//$usu_password=$_POST['password'];
//$usu_rol=$_POST['rol'];
//$usu_email=$_POST['email'];

$usu_usuario="usu004";
$usu_password="usu004";
$usu_rol="guest";
$usu_email="email";

//$sql = " insert into `user` ( `username`,`password`,`rol`,`email`) values (?,?,?,?) ";
$sql = " INSERT INTO user (username, password, rol, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ";

$sentencia=$conexion->prepare($sql);
$sentencia->bind_param('ssss', $usu_usuario, $usu_password, $usu_rol, $usu_email );
$sentencia->execute();

$resultado = $sentencia->get_result();

if ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo json_encode($fila,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);     
}
$sentencia->close();
$conexion->close();
?>
```

Ejecuto esto en el navegador con la url: `http://192.168.0.11/users/borrar_usuario.php` y me devuelve este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\users\borrar_usuario.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\users\borrar_usuario.php on line 14

o bien al ejecutar el otro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\users\alta_usuario.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\users\alta_usuario.php on line 22

La consulta en el phpmyadmin me la ejecuta perfectamente, incluso tengo hecho el login que este sí me funciona:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
//$usu_usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
//$usu_password=$_POST['password'];

$usu_usuario="borja";
$usu_password="12345";

$sql = " SELECT * FROM user WHERE username= ? AND password= ? ";

$sentencia=$conexion->prepare($sql);
$sentencia->bind_param('ss',$usu_usuario,$usu_password);
$sentencia->execute();

$resultado = $sentencia->get_result();
if ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo json_encode($fila,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);     
}
$sentencia->close();
$conexion->close();
?>
```

Comment: aca haces $conexion->close();... donde haces los open correspondientes?

Comment: Lo primero es que `get_result()` sólo funcionará si tienes el driver `mysqlnd` instalado. Si te da error en el primer fetch es muy probable que no tengas ese driver y por eso el resultado es un booleano (false). Escribo lo mismo al menos 10 veces cada día en comentarios: **hay que depurar y hay que controlar el código en todos sus aspectos**, no entiendo por qué la mayoría sigue programando pensando que todo irá bien, no, hay que programar pensando que las cosas pueden salir mal y controlar eso, en tu código no controlas cuando las cosas salen mal y eso es pésimo en programación.

Comment: a la hora de llamar al otro .php ya inicio la conexion entiendo yo y tengo que cerrarla.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @A.Cedano, esto lo he hecho para ver si me servia como funcionalidad, pero veo que no trato errores.. tienes razón alguna sugerencia para dejarlo más pulido? gracias!!! y perdona pero soy muy nuevo en php, en java siempre trato errores lo primero

Comment: quitando el fetch_assoc ya me funciona, pero como puedo por ejemplo controlar si no lo ha insertado por el hecho de que es un registro duplicado?

Comment: Para saber si hubo inserción podrías controlar el estado del `execute`, si es false significa que hubo algún error. Aunque para las inserciones es mejor (a mi juicio), verificar antes de insertar, eso evitaría inserciones fallidas y demasiados saltos en los IDs en caso de muchas inserciones en bucle. A la larga, el código queda más optimizado de ese modo y eres tú quien mantiene siempre el control del mismo, no lanzando inserciones sin verificar antes la duplicidad. En un contexto cliente/servidor esto puede refinarse más, por ejemplo, controlando desde el cliente y evitando los duplicados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues el problema es lo que te dice, el `fetch_assoc`. No puedes usarlo en sentencias que no sean SELECTs ya que se usa para obtener los registros que devuelve una select.
No sé exactamente qué quieres hacer con ese if, así que no te puedo ayudar más. Si la idea simplemente es devolver la info del usuario eliminado/creado tendrías que hacer una select.

Comment: vaya.. gracias soy bastante nuevo en php xD, entonces para por ejemplo delete, modify o insert y devolver que ha sido modificado/eliminado/insertado como sería un select? gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: quitando el fetch_assoc me funciona perfectamente, pero claro si intento volver a entrar un user existente, no me daria ningun mensaje de error, como podria controlar eso? gracias!